# Actualizar array relacionado

Tags: laravel

estoy utilizando laravel y tengo mi función que guarda la fila Préstamo y Detalles de préstamo a su vez. (Modelos)

Esta función para registrar tanto **Prestamo** como **Detalleprestamo** funciona bien, el tema es cuando intento crear la función update. No logro realizarlo con éxito, adjunto mi función Store, como podría quedar para realizar una actualización.

```
    public function store(PrestamoRequest $request)
{
    $prestamo           = new Prestamo;
    $prestamo->socio_id = $request->socio_id;
    $prestamo->monto    = $request->monto;
    $prestamo->cuotas   = $request->cuotas;
    $prestamo->alias    = $request->alias;
    $prestamo->estado   = $request->estado;
    $prestamo->save();
    $idprestamo = $prestamo->id;

    if (count($request->ncuota) > 0) {
        foreach ($request->ncuota as $item => $v) {
            $detallepres = new Detalleprestamo;
            $detallepres->fill([
                'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
                'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
                'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
                'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
                'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]])->save();
        }
        toast('Pago Programados Registrado', 'success');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    } else {
        toast('Error al registrar', 'error');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    }

}
```

Para actualizar el unico cambio que hice fue:

```
    public function update(PrestamoRequest $request, $id)
{
    $prestamo           = Prestamo::findOrFail($id);
    $prestamo->socio_id = $request->socio_id;
    $prestamo->monto    = $request->monto;
    $prestamo->cuotas   = $request->cuotas;
    $prestamo->alias    = $request->alias;
    $prestamo->estado   = $request->estado;
    $prestamo->update();
    $idprestamo = $prestamo->id;

    if (count($request->ncuota) > 0) {
        foreach ($request->ncuota as $item => $v) {
            $detallepres = Detalleprestamo::findOrFail($id);
            $detallepres->fill([
                'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
                'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
                'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
                'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
                'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]])->update();
        }
        toast('Pago Programados Editado', 'success');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    } else {
        toast('Error al registrar', 'error');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    }
}
```

Cuando intento realizar el actualizar desde la vista, el Modelo **Prestamo** si funciona correctamente, pero en el **Detalleprestamo** no se actualiza. Incluso la primera fila se crea nuevamente en la parte superior de mi tabla detalle.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías mostrar el error que te sale al hacer la actualización? Para saber mas concretamente cual puede ser la causa.

Comment: correcto compañero, actualice la información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que haces al hacer update es buscar el mismo `id` de Prestamo, cuando en realidad lo tienes como llave secundaria en tu tabla `Detalleprestamo`, haré unas adecuaciones a tus dos métodos

```
public function store(PrestamoRequest $request)
{
    $prestamo = Prestamo::create($request->only([
        'socio_id',
        'monto',
        'cuotas',
        'alias',
        'estado'
    ]);

    foreach ($request->ncuota as $item => $v) {
            Detalleprestamo::create([
                'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
                'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
                'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
                'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
                'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]
            ]);
        }
        toast('Pago Programados Registrado', 'success');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    } else {
        toast('Error al registrar', 'error');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    }
}

    public function update(PrestamoRequest $request, $id)
{
    $prestamo  = Prestamo::where('id', $id)->update($request->only([
        'socio_id',
        'monto',
        'cuotas',
        'alias',
        'estado'
    ]);

    if (count($request->ncuota) > 0) {
        //Aqui borras los detalles anteriores para crear nuevos
        Detalleprestamo::where('prestamo_id', $id)->delete();
        foreach ($request->ncuota as $item => $v) {
            Detalleprestamo::create([
                'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
                'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
                'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
                'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
                'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]
            ]);
        }
        toast('Pago Programados Editado', 'success');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    } else {
        toast('Error al registrar', 'error');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    }
}
```

Comment: No lo aplique conforme me dijiste, pero la idea de eliminar los **detalles** y volver guardarlos me pareció una buena salida. Solo que me genera nuevos id en la tabla, pero me sirve tu idea. Gracias